# How do I find the error in this xml file?

Tags: android, xml

I'm getting an error *somewhere* in this XML file, but eclipse gives me *no* info about what line and lint shows *no* errors. So,

(a) How on earth am I supposed to find the error?

(b) Can anyone tell what's wrong?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerVertical"
    android:dividerPadding="12dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:showDividers="middle" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_cancel"
        style="?android:actionButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            style="?android:actionBarTabTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/save" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_done"
        style="?android:actionButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            style="?android:actionBarTabTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_cancel"
            android:drawablePadding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think the `style` is not correct? Should it be like `?android:attr/actionBarTabTextStyle`?

Comment: This is valid XML according to http://www.xmlvalidation.com. So you mean that some of the settings are wrong?

Comment: "what is the error?": that's what I'm not getting. Eclipse shows the "red x" in the file manager, but there's nothing else to indicate where or what is wrong. I've managed to "solve" the problem by copying a working file, but I'd still like to know what's wrong so I won't make the same mistake again, whatever it was.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the xml notation
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

EDIT:
Everything else looks fine. Make sure your minApi is 11. You need that for the styles you are using.
There also ways to optimise that layout. One LinearLayout should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logcat message it will show the line number of the error.